# Im having problems adding observation space to a custom Gym enviroment

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am using [this code](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/building-a-reinforcement-learning-environment-using-openai-gym/). I have modified it to work with a car **(0 Left, 1 Straight, 2 Right)**.

I would like to add some observations, such as **Destination (XY), Car Location (XY) bearing (angle), distance_to_destination and bearing_of_destination**, in the hope that the car can find its way to the destination.

I have spent most of the days trying to get this to work, however failed, and failed in many different ways. The crux of the problem seams to be getting the input shape to match.

I think the closest that I have got is this:

```py
def __init__(self):
    low = np.array([-5, -5, -5, -5, -5])
    high = -np.array([ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5])
    self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low, high, dtype=np.float32)
    self.action_space = gym.spaces.Box(low, high, dtype=np.float32)

def reset(self):
    self.state = Myarray# \[\[1,2\], \[1,2\],\[1,2\],\[1,2\],\[1,2\]\]#result.BearingToDest
    self.shower_length = 60000
    return  self.state

def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=24, activation='relu', input_shape=\[ 2\]))
    model.add(Dense(units=24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    return model
```

When I run it and the model loads, the error message is :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_input to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (1, 1, 1, 2)

**Training for 1000000 steps ...
Resetting ML
Interval 1 (0 steps performed)**
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Code that Ran for me is below, it will take some tweeks to get everything learning in the way that I want, but at least its running :)

```
import gym
from gym import Env
import numpy as np
from gym.spaces import Discrete, Box, Dict
import random

Myarray = np.Myarray = [[3, 2]]
# Myarray = [[1][2 ]]
x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = angle = 1


# create a custom class
class ShowerEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self, size=5):
        self.size = size
        high = np.array([[600, 600, 600, 600, 360]])
        low = np.array([[-1, -1, -1, -1, -360]])
        self.state = np.zeros((1, 5), dtype=np.float32)
        self.x1, self.y1, self.x2, self.y2, self.angle = 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
        self.action_space = Discrete(3)
        self.observation_space = gym.spaces.Box(low, high, dtype=np.float32, shape=(1, 5))
        self.shower_length = 60  # duration of  temperature

    def step(self, shower_action):
        x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = angle = 1
        self.shower_length -= 1
        # this line sends a protobuf command to the car program and gets a response ie the true enviroment
        result = client.ChangeCoarse( shower_action - 1, True)#( shower_action - 1, True)
        self.state = np.array([result.X, result.Y, result.DesX, result.DesY, result.BearingToDest])

        if (result.ResetML == True):
            self.reset()
       # x1 = y1 = x2 = y2 = angle = 1
      #  self.state = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2, angle])

        # this should set the reward and gets it from protobuf
        reward =    result.BearingToDest
       # reward = 1  # just put in to make the code run
        if self.shower_length <= 0:
            done = True
        else:
            done = False
        info = ()
        info = {}

        return self.state, reward, done, info

    def render(self):
        pass

    def reset(self):
        result = client.ChangeResetDest()
        self.shower_length = 60000
        self.state = np.array([result.X, result.Y, result.DesX, result.DesY, result.BearingToDest])
        print("Resetting ML")
        return self.state


import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

env = ShowerEnv()
states = env.observation_space.shape
actions =  env.action_space.n


def build_model(states, actions):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(units=24, activation='relu', input_shape=states))
    model.add(Dense(units=24, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(actions, activation='linear'))
    model.add(Flatten())
    return model


# model =build_model(states,actions)
# model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-3), metrics=['mae'])
# del model
#print(model.summary())
from rl.agents import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
import grpc
import Message_pb2_grpc as pb2_grpc, Message_pb2 as pb2


class UnaryClient(object):
    """
     Client for gRPC functionality
     """

    def __init__(self):
        self.host = 'localhost'
        self.server_port = 50052

        # instantiate a channel
        self.channel = grpc.insecure_channel(
            '{}:{}'.format(self.host, self.server_port))

        # bind the client and the server
        self.stub = pb2_grpc.UnaryStub(self.channel)

    def ChangeCoarse(self, val, TF):
        """
        Client function to call the rpc for GetServerResponse
        """
        message = pb2.MessageTo(MoveBoat=True, MoveBoatStep=TF, BoatDelta=val)
        # (message="message", Val=9, MoveBoat=True,MoveBoatStep=True, SailAngle=4, BoatAngle=5.79878, SailDelta=0, BoatDelta=-1)
        #     print(f'{message}')

        return self.stub.GetServerResponse(message)

    def ChangeSail(self, val, TF):
        """
        Client function to call the rpc for GetServerResponse
        """
        message = pb2.MessageTo(MoveBoat=True, MoveBoatStep=TF, SailDelta=val)
        # print(f'{message}')
        return self.stub.GetServerResponse(message)

    def ChangeWindDirection(self, val, TF):
        """
        Client function to call the rpc for GetServerResponse
        """
        message = pb2.MessageTo(MoveBoat=True, MoveBoatStep=TF, WindDelta=val)
        #   print(f'{message}')
        return self.stub.GetServerResponse(message)

    def ChangeResetDest(self):
        """
        Client function to call the rpc for GetServerResponse
        """
        message = pb2.MessageTo(MoveBoat=True, ResetTarget=True)
        # (message="message", Val=9, MoveBoat=True,MoveBoatStep=True, SailAngle=4, BoatAngle=5.79878, SailDelta=0, BoatDelta=-1)
        #     print(f'{message}')
        return self.stub.GetServerResponse(message)


client = UnaryClient()
result = client.ChangeCoarse(90, True)


# if result.
def build_agent(model, actions):
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=900000, window_length=1)
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=model, memory=memory, policy=policy, nb_actions=actions, nb_steps_warmup=100,
                   target_model_update=1e-2)
    return dqn


dqn = build_agent(build_model(states, actions), actions)
dqn.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=1e-5), metrics=['mae'])
dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=1000000, visualize=False, verbose=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, just to make sure, the state you return in *reset* should look something like:

```
self.state = np.array([x1, y1, x2, y2, angle])
```

I don't see the *step* function in your code, but I assume you also modified it to return *self.state*?

Also, your action space is the same as the observation space, it is not normal is it? Given what you said, there are 3 actions so it should be:

```
self.action_space = Discrete(3)
```

Without the full code, it is not really possible to find the cause of your problem. Could you show it?

I also noticed a minus sign which I find strange (although it seems unrelated to your main problem):

```
high = -np.array([ 5,  5,  5,  5,  5])
       ^
      HERE
```

Comment: Thank you for your pointers ErwanF they were very usefull in heelping me create the enviroment, as im playing with ML I also got some ansers from Chat GPT, that where i got the revised class ShowerEnv(Env):
    def __init__(self, size=5):